# Python Kivy ~ PanedWindow

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

Is it possible to have multiple panes within a kivy application so that the user can resize a text input and a label by dragging one of these widgets edges([Much like the container widget inside tkinter](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_panedwindow.htm))? If so can you point me in the right direction. If not, what are the alternate options.

Comment: Look at [resizable behavior](https://github.com/kivy-garden/garden.resizable_behavior).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A **Kivy** *equivalent* will be [BoxLayout](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.boxlayout.html)

If you want to add the *Strech by Drag* at [Splitter](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.splitter.html?highlight=splitter#module-kivy.uix.splitter) - Not that it is not a **Layout**, So some work will be needed in your case.

About resizing of Labels, since labels are getting big by changing *font_size* You'll need to use somthing like [kivyoav](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/kivyoav)'s **AutoSizedLabel**

DISCLAIMER- I'm the author of *kivyoav*...

Comment: I probably should have elaborated a little more with the question. Is it possible to dynamically scale the labels/text input/whatever when the user clicks and drags the edge of one of these widgets(Not talking about the resizing the frame but the widget inside)?